# Saving sbt command output to a file in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running cmd like "sbt dependencyTree" but it gives outlut like, first few lines some info about versions and all then gives the origanl cmd output.

Is there a way to directly put the cmd output in file using sbt cmd.

eg. **sbt  dependencyTree**

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.3 (Eclipse Adoptium Java 17.0.7)
[info] loading settings for project http4s-build from build.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /Users/chandrapratapprajapati/sbt-local/http4s/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] resolving key references (63042 settings) ...
[info] set scmInfo to https://github.com/http4s/http4s
[info] set current project to http4s (in build file:/Users/chandrapratapprajapati/sbt-local/http4s/)
[info] org.http4s:http4s_2.13:0.23.19-6-b22f722-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.http4s:http4s-scalafix-internal_2.13:0.23.19-6-b22f722-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info]   +-ch.epfl.scala:scalafix-core_2.13:0.10.4 [S]
[info]     +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-typesafe-config_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-core_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | | +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-pprint_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | | | +-com.lihaoyi:fansi_2.13:0.3.0
[info]     | | | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.13:0.2.7 (evicted by: 0.3.0)
[info]     | | | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.13:0.3.0 [S]
[info]     | | | |
[info]     | | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.13.10 [S]
[info]     | | | | +-io.github.java-diff-utils:java-diff-utils:4.12
[info]     | | | | +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.9.0
```

---

I want the output only like below :

```
[info] org.http4s:http4s_2.13:0.23.19-6-b22f722-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.http4s:http4s-scalafix-internal_2.13:0.23.19-6-b22f722-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info]   +-ch.epfl.scala:scalafix-core_2.13:0.10.4 [S]
[info]     +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-typesafe-config_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-core_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | | +-com.geirsson:metaconfig-pprint_2.13:0.10.0 [S]
[info]     | | | +-com.lihaoyi:fansi_2.13:0.3.0
[info]     | | | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.13:0.2.7 (evicted by: 0.3.0)
[info]     | | | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.13:0.3.0 [S]
[info]     | | | |
[info]     | | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.13.10 [S]
[info]     | | | | +-io.github.java-diff-utils:java-diff-utils:4.12`
[info]     | | | | +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.9.0
```

IS there a way to achieve that.

Comment: Don't think that's possible out of the box. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995627/redirect-stdout-from-sbt-run-to-file

Comment: I see that you're trying to write the dependency tree to file. What worked for me is: 1) add `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")` to plugins.sbt, and 2) execute `sbt dependencyBrowseTreeHtml`. The dependency tree is written to the target/tree.html file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by running the following:

```
sbt 'dependencyGraph/toFile "/path/to/output"'
```

If you are running from the sbt REPL you can omit the single quotes around the command (and `sbt` as well, of course).

Please note that this works fine on individual modules but not on aggregates ([it's a known issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6627)), so if you need to run it on a multi-module project you'll have to manually run it scoped on individual sub-projects, e.g.:

```
sbt 'someSubModuleName/depedencyGraph/toFile "/path/to/output"'
```

The result will contain only the dependency tree, without the `[info]` prefix, hopefully that's not a problem for you.